# Passing certificates/keys in kubeconfig throws an JSON error

Tags: kubernetes

Using Kubectl client (1.7.0) on Windows to connect to remote cluster.

The config file in Windows ( located in .kube) directory is configured as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\ca.crt
    server: https://10.99.70.153:6443
  name: devo
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: devo
    user: admindevo
  name: devo
current-context: devo
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admindevo
  user:
    client-certificate-data: C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\apiserver.crt
    client-key-data: C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\apiserver.key
```

These certificate files I have downloaded from the remote system to my localhost. But this does not work. Throws the following error->

```
C:\Windows\kubernetes>kubectl   version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-29T23:15:59Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
error: Error loading config file "C:\Users\DK05478/.kube/config": [pos 107]: json: error decoding base64 binary 'C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\ca.crt': illegal base64 data at input byte 1
```

How can I fix this issue? whats that I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-data` suffix from `certificate-authority-data`, `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data`. Like what @sfgroups said, the `xxx-data` param is meant for a base64-encoded cert/key.

Once you do, your kubeconfig should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\ca.crt
    server: https://10.99.70.153:6443
  name: devo
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: devo
    user: admindevo
  name: devo
current-context: devo
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admindevo
  user:
    client-certificate: C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\apiserver.crt
    client-key: C:\Users\DK05478\.kube\apiserver.key
```

Answer (score 0):

`certificate-authority-data: , client-certificate-data:, client-key-data:` reference to the file. I think you need base64 encoded keys value here. you can look `.kube/config` file from your cluster master.

look at this page for `base64`  usage example https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/